Computing probability when all events are independent from each other individually but they can't all happen
I was given this question:

Given a, b, c are all independent to each other pair-wise, p(a) = p(b) = p(c) =
0.5, p(abc) = 0, what is p(ab~c)?, ~c is when c doesn't happen.

I can calculate it by doing this p(ab) = p(abc) + p(ab~c) => p(ab~c) = p(a) * p(b) - p(abc) = 0.25. But I  when I calculate the total table it just doesn't add up to 1. Is it because we don't have enough information to calculate the table of probability ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is literally impossible for this to happen. If all three events are independent and happen with probability $0.5$, then $p(abc) = (0.5)^3 = 0.125 \neq 0$.

Yes I failed to add that the independent was only pair-wise, thanks for pointing that out!

It does all add up.
You have shown that $p(a b \bar c) = 0.25$
by symmetry ...
$$ p( a b \bar c ) = p(a \bar b c) = p(\bar a b c) = 0.25$$
now $$p(a \bar b \bar c) + p(a b \bar c) = p(a \bar c) = 0.25 \implies p(a \bar b \bar c)=0$$
by symmetry ...
$$ p( a \bar b \bar c ) = p(\bar a \bar b c) = p(\bar a b \bar c) = 0$$
finally...
$$p(\bar a \bar b \bar c) + p(a \bar b \bar c) = p(\bar b \bar c) = 0.25 \implies p(\bar a \bar b \bar c)=0.25$$

Oh I somehow assumed that p(a~b~c) = 0.125. Thank you for  the answer.

Since events $a, b,$ and $c$ can't all occur, we can conclude that $(a\cap b)\subseteq  \neg c $. This in turn tells us that $\Pr(ab\neg c)=\Pr(ab)$, and by pairwise independence, $Pr(ab)=Pr(a)Pr(b)=\frac12\cdot \frac12=\frac14$
Note: The situation in this problem can be exemplified by the following experiment: Flip a fair coin twice noting the order of the two tosses. Event $a$ is get heads on the first toss; event $b$ is get tails on the second toss;  and event $c$ is get the same thing on both tosses.
